# VSCode 1.20.1 will not stop at any Node.js v8 breakpoints, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get VSCode 1.20.1 to break at a breakpoint in my project, but it simply refuses to break (at least with the inspector protocol).  I've distilled this down to a 3 line Node.js sample project which can be found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/mvachhar/vscode-nodejs-debug-test), I'll paste the relevant sections below.

The `index.js` program is a simple Hello World with a delay to avoid any debugger attach races (more on that later).

```
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Hello'); //Breakpoint is set here
}, 5000);
```

The launch.json is below:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Normal Run",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/node",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy",
                "--inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:5858"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.js",
            "args": [],
            "env": {
                "DOCKER_ARGS": "-p5858:5858"
            },
            "address": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 5858,
            "timeout": 60000,
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "smartStep": true,
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/src"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that Node.js is running in Docker in the standard `node:8` container with a volume mount of the local source directory (that is what the runTimeExecutable is for, see [GitHub](https://github.com/mvachhar/vscode-nodejs-debug-test)).  If I use Wireshark to monitor port 5858, I can see the debugger attach and decode all messages.  Strangely, VSCode issues the `Runtime.runIfWaitingForDebugger` immediately, and then later issues the `Debugger.setBreakpointByURL` message that seems to be accepted by Node.js (it successfully returns a Location for the breakpoint).  I have the 5 second timeout in the code just in case this race is the cause of the problem (which it does not seem to be).

As an aside, if I use my host Node.js (6.11.4) with the protocol as `legacy` (or `auto` which chooses `legacy`) and comment out the `runtimeArgs`, `runtimeExecutable`, etc. VSCode hits the breakpoint.  If I force the protocol to `inspector` (which is experimental in 6.11.4) and add back the runtimeArgs (but not executable) the debugger attaches but no breakpoint is hit, essentially the same behavior as with the Docker node:8 above.

What am I doing wrong here?  This problem originally started in a new TypeScript project using sourcemaps and mocha, etc. but I've boiled it down to this.

Comment: Here is a datapoint, if I remove "console": "integratedTerminal" the debugger attaches every time.